# The importance of non-zero Chern number for conduction bands

Tags: condensed-matter

I have a 4 by 4 Hamiltonian. And, I have calculated the Chern number for 4 bands. Valence bands have zero Chern numbers. But the Chern numbers of conduction bands are not zero. What is the physical impact and importance of such a system? And, how this non-zero Chern number could be observed in the laboratory?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the Chern numbers of each of the band?

Comment: For the highest valence band and the band below it,  the Chern number is zero. For the lowest conduction band, it is -1, and for the band above it, the Chern number is +1.

Comment: The Hall conductance of the system is given by the total Chern number of all the filled bands. In this case, it seems like the Hall conductance is 0.

Comment: I understand that the nontrivial band is not fully-occupied, and my question is the physical consequence of such a partially-filled nontrivial band. I think that in such a case, it might be difficult to observe topological effects experimentally. But how about the edge states? Nontrivial bands yield nontrivial edge states. Then, there might be a possibility of physical observation?